# Merge json arrays with duplicate keys

Tags: arrays, json, bash, inner-join, jq

I want to merge two json arrays with help of `jq`. Each object in arrays contains name field, which allow me to group by and merge two arrays into one.

LABELS

```json
[
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "description": "master"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_branch",
    "description": "main"
  }
]
```

RUNNERS

```json
[
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "runner": "power",
    "runner_tag": "macos"
  },
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "runner": "power",
    "runner_tag": "ubuntu"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_branch",
    "runner": "tester",
    "runner_tag": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "development",
    "runner": "dev",
    "runner_tag": "ubuntu"
  }
]
```

Desired Output

```json
[
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "description": "master",
    "runner": "power",
    "runner_tag": "macos"
  },
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "description": "master",
    "runner": "power",
    "runner_tag": "ubuntu"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_branch",
    "description": "main",
    "runner": "tester",
    "runner_tag": ""
  }
]
```

I tried with following script, but power_branch entry was override, instead i want another entry with different runner_tag

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

LABELS='[{"name": "power_branch","description": "master"},{"name": "test_branch","description": "main"}]'
RUNNERS='''
[
  { "name": "power_branch", "runner": "power", "runner_tag": "macos" },
  { "name": "power_branch", "runner": "power", "runner_tag": "ubuntu" },
  { "name": "test_branch", "runner": "tester", "runner_tag": "" },
  { "name": "development", "runner": "dev", "runner_tag": "ubuntu" }
]
'''

FINAL=$(jq -s '[ .[0] + .[1] | group_by(.name)[] | select(length > 1) | add]' <(echo $LABELS) <(echo $RUNNERS))
echo $FINAL
```

OUTPUT

```json
[
  {
    "name": "power_branch",
    "description": "master",
    "runner": "power",
    "runner_tag": "ubuntu"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_branch",
    "description": "main",
    "runner": "tester",
    "runner_tag": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two files `labels.json` and `runners.json`, you could read in the latter (runners) as a variable using `--argjson` and append to each element of the input array (labels) using `map` the corresponding fields determined by `select`.

```sh
jq --argjson runners "$(cat runners.json)" '
  map(.name as $name | . + ($runners[] | select(.name == $name)))
' labels.json
```

However, this reads the whole runners array into your shells command line space (`--argjson` takes two strings: a name and a value) which can easily overflow if the runners array gets big enough.

Therefore, instead of using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) `"$(…)"`, you could read in the runners file directly using either `--slurpfile` for the cost of another iteration level `[][]`, or (despite the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) saying not to - read more about it in the comments) using `--argfile` with just a single iteration level as before:

```sh
jq --slurpfile runners runners.json '
  map(.name as $name | . + ($runners[][] | select(.name == $name)))
' labels.json
```

```sh
jq --argfile runners runners.json '
  map(.name as $name | . + ($runners[] | select(.name == $name)))
' labels.json
```

To circumvent all these issues, @peak [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567330/merge-json-arrays-with-duplicate-keys#comment124749465_70567476) using `input` for each file together with the `-n` option. Note that this requires the two files to be provided in this exact order as they are being read in sequentially.

```sh
jq -n 'input as $runners | input |
  map(.name as $name | . + ($runners[] | select(.name == $name)))
' runners.json labels.json
```

As the second `input` (labels) is passed on directly as the filter's main input (in contrast to runners, which is stored in a variable for later use), this could be further simplified by removing again the `-n` option (order of the files still matters):

```sh
jq 'input as $runners |
  map(.name as $name | . + ($runners[] | select(.name == $name)))
' runners.json labels.json
```

Finally, here's yet another approach using the [SQL-style operators](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#SQL-StyleOperators) `INDEX` and `JOIN` which were introduced in jq v1.6. This also employs the technique using just one `input` and also the order of the files still matters as we need the runners array as the filter's primary input.

```sh
jq '
  JOIN(INDEX(input[]; .name); .name) | map(select(.[1]) | add)
' runners.json labels.json
```

Comment: Note that your first snippet can fail if `runners.json` is quite large.

Comment: Simpler: `jq --argfile runners runners.json '...$runners[]...' labels.json`

Comment: @ikegami That's why I added the second one. And `--argfile` is simpler but deprecated. The jq manual says "Do not use."

Comment: The issue with `--argfile` is that it behaves unpredictably when provided a file that contains a stream of JSON docs. There's absolutely no problems in using `--argfile` for files containing a single JSON document as we are here. The following is how the warning should read: "*Don't use `--argfile` for files containing a stream of JSON documents. Use `--slurpfile` for such files instead.*"

Comment: I would *love* to have back the `--argfile` functionality but since its deprecation I was afraid that one day with a new release it will silently be removed, rendering filters still relying on it a ticking bomb. If, however, its (intended) use with a single document is **not** deprecated, then why doesn't it simply throw an error just like `--argjson` does when fed with a stream instead of a single document? (See `jq -n --argjson a '{}{}' .`) The deprecation notice could then be removed entirely. Or is there more to it?

Comment: There's no mention of removal. All the docs say is "do not use". And there's a very good reason to avoid using it ...for streams. There's nothing about it being removed from future releases. And it would be insane to remove a widely use option, especially one that works correctly for what it was meant to do. (If it was up to me, I'd deprecate the behaviour for streams, eventually changing it to give an error or create a loop.) I'm busy right now, but I'll see about creating a ticket about clarifying the wording and/or intent

Comment: Oh, that's reassuring! Thank you for the clarification and your efforts.

Comment: One way to circumvent all the issues here with --argfile/--slurpfile/--argjson 
would be to use the -n command-line optino with one `input` for each file.  By the way,
--argfile was deprecated (rather rashly in my opinion) mainly because incorrect documentation 
had led to confusion.  Its behavior was, to the best of my recollection,
never actually "unpredictable" in the sense of erratic or indeterminate.

Comment: @peak, True, "unpredictable" isn't right word. What I meant is: Produces a value in an unknown format. If the input is expected to a stream of documents, a valid input might get you an array of the JSON documents as expected. Or it might not. You may or may not be able to fix the input (depending on the specifics of the input format). on the other hand, `--slurpfile` always produces the expected array. [Example](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/dce9a1f958cc58181de670a3673b5e8b).