# Jq how to merge two json objects

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to merge two JSON objects that has a common key

Object A

```json
{
  "extensions": { 
    "app_name": "extensions-prod"
  },
  "plugins": { 
    "app_name": "plugins-prod" 
  }
}
```

Object B

```json
{
  "plugins": { 
    "project_name": "plugins-prod" 
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
  "plugins": { 
    "project_name": "plugins-prod",
    "app_name": "plugins-prod" 
  }
}
```

I did look into other SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70567330/merge-json-arrays-with-duplicate-keys) but were not very useful as the structure I have is different. Also the json objects are bash variables and not contained in a file.

[Edit]
I would not know what the common key would be since the JSON objects are being generated dynamically in a CI environment.

Comment: How about a simple deep merge using `*`? `jq 'input * {plugins}' <<< "$objA $objB"` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nstjG0tu4Kk)

Comment: @pmf that's a very elegant and straightforward solution. Although, I wouldn't know what this common key is going to be because the JSON is created dynamically in a CI environment. I have updated the OP since I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Edit] I would not know what the common key would be

With `in` you can find out if a given key is present in a given object. Thus, you could use `with_entries` to iterate over an object's fields, and `select` (keep) only those entries whose `.key` is present in another object. If object A is "trimmed" that way, it can then be (deeply) merged into object B using `*`:

```bash
jq -n --argjson objA "$objA" --argjson objB "$objB" \
  '$objB * ($objA | with_entries(select(.key | in($objB))))'
```

This assumes (in accordance with your sample data) that object B only contains common keys, such that only object A has to be trimmed to the keys of object B. If this isn't generally the case, symmetrically treat object B using object A. In fact, you could just define the trimming in a parametrizable function, and use it mutually on both objects:

```bash
jq -n --argjson objA "$objA" --argjson objB "$objB" '
  def trim_to($o): with_entries(select(.key | in($o)));
  ($objB | trim_to($objA)) * ($objA | trim_to($objB))
'
```

Given the sample data, both output:

```json
{
  "plugins": {
    "project_name": "plugins-prod",
    "app_name": "plugins-prod"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution does not assume that the intersection of key names is a singleton

```
jq -n --argjson a "$A" --argjson b "$B" '

  def i: (.[0] | unique) as $u | $u - ($u - .[1]); 
  def k: [$a, $b] | map(keys_unsorted) | i;
  [k[] | { (.): ($b[.] + $a[.]) } ] | add
'
```

Answer (score -1):

This should achieve what's expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

A='{
  "extensions": { 
    "app_name": "extensions-prod"
  },
  "plugins": { 
    "app_name": "plugins-prod" 
  }
}'
B='
{
  "plugins": { 
    "project_name": "plugins-prod" 
  }
}'

jq -s 'map(to_entries) |
       add |
       group_by(.key) |
       map(select(length == 2) |
           { key: first | .key,
             value: map(.value) | add
           }
          ) |
       from_entries' <<< "$A $B"
```